# Add pattern to gitignore that will match files that don't contain a substring in a directory

Tags: git

I have a directory `dir` in there are a few files named with the convention `filename.txt` and `filename_base.txt`.

So my directory could look like this:

```
dir/randomstringA.txt
dir/randomstringA_base.txt
dir/randomstringB.txt
dir/randomstringB_base.txt
dir/randomstringC.txt
dir/randomstringC_base.txt
```

I want to keep any files ending in `_base.txt` (i.e. ignore those that don't). I would say I want to ignore any file in `dir` that doesn't end with `_base.txt` but I don't see how to ignore files that don't match a pattern, only those that do match.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to move the `_base.txt` files into a different directory then ignore the entire content of one of the two directories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
dir/*.txt
!dir/*_base.txt
```

Comment: Note that this ignores all files that match `dir/*.txt` then excludes those that match `dir/*_base.txt` from being ignored.

Comment: That's fine, those are the only two file patterns in that directory